# How to add new layout to fragment on press of a button? Is RecyclerView the right way?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a LinearLayout view which I want to replicate on the press of a button (which is part of the linear layout itself). Basically, something like in the picture below, where pressing the plus button adds a new row (and replaces the plus button with the minus one).

I am looking at RecyclerView to accomplish this, and following the steps at (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview-in-kotlin/).

However, I am having some doubts that this is the right way to go. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use Recyclerview and add items with the help of ArrayList and notify the adapter. And also you can fetch values easily in Recyclerview.